# Search for *.swo

Tags: terminal, bash

I think this should be an easy one, but it's got me stumped.

When I use the following, it finds the file.

```
$ ls -al  .bash_*.sw*   
-rw-r--r--  1 damiensawyer  staff  12288 27 Nov 07:39 .bash_profile.swo
```

But when I use this, it doesn't find it.

```
$ ls -al *.sw*      
ls: *.sw*: No such file or directory
```

I expected the second command to also return `.bash_profile.swo`.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Using `ls`

The problem is that your file has two dots, not one. You need to account for that:

```
ls -al .*.sw*
```

This will match any file that begins with a dot (invisible files like `.DS_Store`) and also ends with `.sw*`.

`.swa` as well as `.swz` will match.

---

## Using `find`

You can use the following to find all files with the same extension (`swo` in the case below) in a directory.

```
find ~ -iname *swo
```

`-iname` finds a case insensitive match.

---

You can search for that/those specific file(s) using this:

```
find .bash_*.sw*
```

---

<sup>Note: Using `~` as the path will search your entire home directory.</sup>

Comment: Thanks Zach. I'm aware of using find. I'm wondering if there's a reason that ls isn't working. Is it a limitation of ls?

Comment: I've edited my answer. @DamienSawyer

Comment: aah cool. So, the takeaway from this should be 'the star doesn't match the period'?

Comment: It *does* match a period, but it assumes that everything after the first period is the part that needs to match `sw*`. @DamienSawyer

Comment: Actually, it isn't the "two dots" that is the problem, it is the fact that the first dot is the first character. In Unix this the convention for hiding files. *.sw* would match red.and.joe.are.sworn.enemies, since this is not a "hidden" file.

Answer (score 6):

This is not actually caused by `ls`, since `ls` never expands patterns.

The decision about how to expand glob patterns (patterns containing `*` and `?`) is **made by the shell**.  Your shell is most likely `bash`.

By default `bash` does not perform [path expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) on dotfiles.  However, it can do so either by explicitly writing the `.` (as you discovered already) or by turning on the `dotglob` option.  From the bash manpage:

> **dotglob** If set, bash includes filenames beginning with a `.' in the results of pathname expansion.

To demonstrate, let's just print the expansion with `echo` instead of `ls`:

```
$ touch .bash_profile.swo

$ echo .*.swo
.bash_profile.swo

$ echo *.swo
*.swo

$ shopt -s dotglob

$ echo *.swo
.bash_profile.swo
```

Futher discussion can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40662/what-is-the-setting-in-bash-for-globbing-to-control-whether-matches-dot-files).

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `ls` only shows files that begin with a `.` you have to explicitly have the first `.` in the file glob.

Thus the following will work:

```
ls .*swo
```

Unix shells expand the glob before `ls` sees the file names.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I did actually try -a, however it doesn't appear that your first sample works. I think that you need the leading period.

Comment: Hey, did you mean 'first' instead of 'worst'?

Answer (score 2):

These patterns (`*.sw*` and the like) are known as [globs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).

As @Mark and @Zach Gates have noted, globs do not match files whose names begin with a period unless you explicitly include a `.` at the beginning of the pattern. This is because in UNIX-like systems (such as OS X), files that begin with a dot are considered 'hidden' files and are generally not shown by default.

Glob matching is actually done by your shell (`bash` by default), not by individual commands such as `ls`.
As the bash manual explains under [Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion-1):

> After word splitting... Bash scans each word for the characters ‘`*`’, ‘`?`’, and ‘`[`’. If one of these characters appears, then the word is regarded as a pattern, and replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of filenames matching the pattern (see Pattern Matching). If no matching filenames are found,...the word is left unchanged.
>
> When a pattern is used for filename expansion, the character ‘`.`’ at the start of a filename or immediately following a slash must be matched explicitly, unless the shell option `dotglob` is set.